# How can I merge two Python dictionaries additive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to merge two Python dictionaries additive, like this:

```
 a = {'result': {'sessionId': '111'}}
 b = {'result': {'completelyOtherSessionId': '100'}}
 ##magic##
 c = {'result': {'sessionId': '111', 'completelyOtherSessionId': '100'}}
```

Comment: I see the keys `sessionId` and `sessionsId` are slightly different. Is that intentional?

Comment: Have you looked at a single page of documentation or such about python dictionaries? Have you googled "python merge dictionaries"?

Comment: Of course! But all I could find was the dict.update(otherdict) function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Python2/3 function that will not alter the dicts you give it. It will create a new one and attempt to combine them all. Keep in mind that it doesn't handle collisions in any advanced way. It simply overwrites it with the right-most dict parameter.

```
def add_dicts(*dicts):
    ret, dicts = dict(), list(dicts)
    dicts.insert(0, ret)
    try:
        red = reduce
    except NameError:
        red = __import__("functools").reduce
    red(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x, dicts)
    return ret
```

Example:

```
a = {"a": 1}
b = {"b": 2}
c = {"c": 3}

var = add_dicts(a, b, c)
print(a)  # => {"a": 1}
print(b)  # => {"b": 2}
print(c)  # => {"c": 3}
print(var)  # => {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: What's with the funky import? Why not **`from functools import reduce as red`**?

Comment: No particular reason. PyCharm doesn't like when I have imports throughout my code. With the `__import__` statement, you don't really lose anything.

Comment: Thanks, but the function you wrote is in the result very similar to the dict.update(otherdict) function.

Comment: Except it takes an arbitrary number of dicts instead of doing them manually and it returns a new one meaning g the original dictionaries are left in tact.

Comment: @Goodies Your solution does not solve OP's problem. Function `add_dicts(a, b)` does not return `c` that OP expects.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = {'result': {'sessionId': '111'}}
>>> b = {'result': {'sessionsId': '100'}}
>>> с = a.copy()
>>> for key in c:
>>>     c[key].update(b[key])
>>> print(c)
{'result': {'sessionId': '111', 'sessionsId': '100'}}
```

Please understand that this solution only works for your specific case (`a` and `b`'s values are also dictionaries). Otherwise the `update` method would not be available and you'd get an `AttributeError` exception.

Comment: This is a very good solution for my problem. With this i could write a universal function. But its a little bit confusing that im the only one with this problem...